# Show that solution of $T(n)=T(n-2)+2\log n$ is $O(n\log n)$

Tags: algorithms, substitution

I am solving this question from solution manual, but stuck at this point:

```
T(n)=T(n-2)+2logn
T(n)=O(nlogn)
T(n)<= c(n-2)log(n-2)+2logn
T(n)<=cnlog(n-2)-2clog(n-2)+2logn
```

Now I am stuck at this, how will I reduce log(n-2). So, I can get my required solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$T(n) = T(n-2)+2 \log n$$
$$T(n) = 2 \log n + 2 \log(n-2)+ ... \text{ upto }\frac{n}{2}\text{ terms} $$
$$T(n) < 2 \log n + 2 \log n + ... \text{ upto }\frac{n}{2}\text{ terms} $$
$$T(n) < 2 (n-2) \log n < cn \log n $$

By considering half of terms from $\frac{n}{2}$ to $n$
$$T(n) > 2\log(\frac{n}{2}) + 2\log(\frac{n}{2}+2)+... \text{ upto }\frac{n}{2}\text{ terms} $$
$$T(n) > 2\log(\frac{n}{2}) + 2\log(\frac{n}{2})+... \text{ upto }\frac{n}{2}\text{ terms} $$
$$T(n) > n\log\frac{n}{2}$$
$$T(n) > n\log{n} - n \log 2$$
Since, $n\log2$ is of lower order,
$$T(n) > d n \log n$$

Hence, $T(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$

**Alternatively**,
You can use Stirling's approximation to get $\log n!=n\log n-n+ \text{O}(\log n)$

As, 
$$T(n)=2 \log n + 2 \log (n-2) + ...  \text{ upto }\frac{n}{2}\text{ terms} $$
$$T(n) = 2 \log (2^{\frac{n}{2}}(\frac{n}{2})!)$$
$$T(n)=2 \log(2^\frac{n}{2})+2\log ((\frac{n}{2})!)$$

With Stirling's approximation,
$$T(n)= n \log 2 + 2 (\frac{n}{2}\log \frac{n}{2}) - 2 \frac{n}{2} + 2 \text{ O}(\log\frac{n}{2})$$

After removing lower order terms,
$$T(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$$

Comment: I have not understand two points int it First, in second step why do you not write it as T(n)=2logn+(n-2)log(n-2) and Second why do you change the sign from less to greater than?

Comment: 1. $T(n)=T(n-2)+2\log(n)$, So By substituting $n-2$ to that equation, $T(n)=(T(n-4) + 2\log(n-2)) + 2\log n$. By doing the same step, we get a summation which yields the second step.

Comment: 2. That's how you prove for $\Theta$ notation. Which is a stronger result than $O$ itself. I recommend you to search more on definitions of Big-O and Theta notation before proceeding.

Comment: I did few edits for summations to make it more clear for you

Answer (score 1):

For $m\in \Bbb N$ we have $0\le 2\log m<\int_m^{m+2}\log t\, dt.$

For $3\le n\in \Bbb N$  we have  $T(n)=2\log n+2\log(n-2)+...+2\log A+T(B)$ where if $n$ is odd then $A=3$ and $B=1,$ while if $n$ is even then $A=2$ and $B=0.$

In either case we have  $$0\le 2\log n+2\log (n-2)+...+2\log A<\int_n^{n+2}\log t\, dt +\int_{n-2}^n \log t\, dt+...+\int_A^{A+2}\log t \,dt=$$ $$=\int_A^{n+2}\log t\, dt=$$ $$=O((n+2)\log (n+2)-(n+2))=O(n\log n)$$ because $\int \log t\, dt =t\log t -t,$ and because $\frac { (n+2)\log (n+2)-(n+2)}{n\log  n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

**Well, I can give you a simple answer as you do it in the substitution method**

You got,
$$T(n)\leq cn\log(n-2)-2c\log(n-2)+2\log n$$
Since, $\log (n-2) < \log n$
$$T(n) \leq cn \log n - 2 c \log (n-2) + 2 \log n$$

Since, $\log(n-2)$ and $\log n$ are of lower order than $n \log n$

$$T(n) \leq cn \log n + \text{some negligible terms compared to }n \log n$$
$$T(n) = \text{O}(n\log n)$$

But, I would not accept this as a correct answer. It's a cheat!